# Converting a createLabel function into a Table View with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

Using Titanium for a class.  I have a function that extracts my JSON data and creates labels and eventListeners.  I need to make this project into a table opposed to just labels but I'm having a tough time doing so and can't quite figure it out.  Here's my working code with labels.  This is only my second coding class so any patience and insider tips and tricks will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks guys

```
Ti.UI.setBackgroundImage("347.png");

var bands = {
    "sevenfold": {
        "headTitle": "Avenged Sevenfold",
        "footTitle": "Orange County Metal Band",
        "members": [
            {
                "name": "M. Shadows", 
                "info": "Lead Singer.  Known for his raspy yet powerful vocals"
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Synyster Gates", 
                "info": "Lead guitarist and backup vocalist.  Known for technical        solos and melodic riffs."
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Zacky Vengeance",
                "info": "Rhythm guitarist and backup vocalist.  Capable of tight and fast riffs and harmonizing with lead guitar parts. "
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Johnny Christ",
                "info": "Bassist.  Contributes heavy grooves as well as intricate undertones to the rhythm section."
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Arin Iljey", 
                "info": "Drummer.  New-comer to the band.  Filled in for the late Jimmy 'The Rev' Sullivan."
            }, 
        ]
    },
    "adtr": {
        "headTitle": "A Day To Remember",
        "footTitle": "Ocala Based Pop-Punk Band",
        "members":  [
            {
                "name": "Jeremey McKinnon", 
                "info": "Lead Singer.  Capable of hitting clean high notes as well as low screams."
            }, 
            {
                "name": "Neil Westfall",
                "info": "Rhythm guitarist and backup vocalist.  Plays fast punk inspired rhythm sections while contributing back up screams during live shows."
            },
            {
                "name": "Joshua Woodard",
                "info": "Bassist.  Contributes to the heavy tones of the rhythm section."
            },
            {
                "name": "Kevin Skaff", 
                "info": "Lead guitarist and backup vocalist.  Plays the melodic section of songs and aids Jeremy with clean vocals both in the studio and on live shows."
            },
            {
                "name": "Alex Shelnut", 
                "info": "Drummer.  Adds fast punk fills with metal influenced double bass beats."
            }
        ]
    }
};


var mainWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: "Band Members",
    backgroundImage: "347.png"
});

var navWindow = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow({
    window: mainWindow  
});


var getDetail = function(){
    var detailWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title: this.text,
        backgroundColor: "white"
    });
    var detailText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: this.details,
        top: 30,
        left: 15,
        right: 15
    });
    detailWindow.add(detailText);
    navWindow.openWindow(detailWindow);
};

var makeUI = function(){
    var spacing = 30;
    for(n in bands){
        var titleLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text: bands[n].headTitle,
            left: 30,
            right: 30,
            borderRadius: 5,
            top: spacing,
            height: 25,
            textAlign: "center",
            backgroundColor: "#333",
            font: {fontSize: 22, fontFamily: "Verdana", fontWeight: "bold"},
            color: "#fafafa"
        });
        spacing = titleLabel.top + titleLabel.height + 10;
        for(m in bands[n].members){
            var itemLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: bands[n].members[m].name,
                details: bands[n].members[m].info,
                left: 30,
                right: 30,
                borderRadius: 5,
                textAlign: "center",
                top: spacing,
                height: 25,
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                font: {fontSize: 22, fontFamily: "Verdana"},
                color: "#333"
            });
            mainWindow.add(itemLabel);
            spacing = itemLabel.top + itemLabel.height + 10;
            itemLabel.addEventListener("click", getDetail);
        }
        mainWindow.add(titleLabel);
        spacing = itemLabel.top + itemLabel.height + 40;
    }
};



makeUI();


navWindow.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Titanium Kitchen sink application which contains templates and examples for all the different UI elements. The app itself is not a good example of how to architect your entire application but it provides some excellent examples of how to build tableViews.

[Titanium Kitchen Sink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink)

Download it, import it into Ti Studio as an existing project, build it and view it in the simulator or on a device.. Find the control you want, see the options and follow the code examples.

In your existing app, you are adding labels to a window and then keeping a spacing counter for where to layout your next label.

The tableView is the right UI control to use.

- create a tableView object(position, style etc..)
- create an array of tableRow objects (like how you are with labels now)
- tableView.data = myTableRowsArray;
- add tableView to your window
- you're up and running